# Get the IIS Web Root Path using dotNet

Tags: .net, iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I need to determine the actual literal path to the web site root directory. The application may be loaded on other servers and the web root may be in a different location like "E:\projects\development\wwwroot", or "f:\webroot". Using `getDirectoryFromPath(expandPath("/"))` returns the ColdFusion web root of c:\ColdFusion10\testInstance\wwwroot. I need the IIS7 web root path, like c:\inetpub\wwwroot. To get this, I have tried calling the .net class HttpRuntime as `<cfset httpClass = createObject("dotnet","System.Web.HttpRuntime","c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.System.Web.dll")>` in order to get the AppDomainAppPath property. ColdFusion throws the error 
"Class System.Web.HttpRuntime not found in the specified assembly list. The assembly that contains the class must be provided to the assembly attribute".

According to Microsoft's MSDN library, the following is true:
HttpRuntime Class
Namespace:  System.Web
Assembly:  System.Web (in System.Web.dll)

What I have done:

1. Edited the class definition to "Web.HttpRuntime" and "HttpRuntime"
2. Called and dumped `<cfset domainClass = createObject("dotnet","System.appDomain","c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll")>` to prove the environment and methodology

Environment:
Server on a closed network, no connection to internet
ColdFusion 10 update 14/multiple instances
Windows 2008r2 with IIS7
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed

Am I maybe missing another assembly that this one depends on? I'm no expert on dotNet, so I may be missing something very basic, here. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the CGI variables. See here https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/CGI+environment+(CGI+Scope)+variables

Comment: Update: Thanks, TechMark2K. Slick trick. Although TechMark2K is correct, the reason I initially went for the .NET solution was because the application needs to be completely portable, if possible. The actual web root could be anywhere and the application directory may be the web root or a subdirectory or a web server virtual directory. ColdFusion will only be aware of its own application root and internal web root locations. I need to get what IIS7 sees as the web root, so I can iterate down the paths and set variables. As far as I know, the only way is to make a call to the .NET framework.

Comment: Leigh: I tried the older version, but get the same resulting error.

Comment: @user1172456 - Weird. I assume you are running 64bit? BTW: S.O. does not notify someone you left a new comment unless you: a) post a comment beneath their "answer" or b) put an `@` symbol in front of their username :)

Answer (score 1):

I see that your web root folder is called `wwwroot` then you can do this:

`<cfset rootDir = left(getBaseTemplatePath(), len(getBaseTemplatePath()) - find(reverse('wwwroot'), reverse(getBaseTemplatePath())) + 2)>`

`<cfdump var="#rootDir#" />`

Answer (score 0):

I tried and got the same error in my environment. I am guessing it is because there are two versions of System.Web.dll on my filesystem: Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 and Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ . I changed the path to point to the older version and it worked fine:

```
 httpClass = createObject("dotnet"
          , "System.Web.HttpRuntime"
          , "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll")
```